# FBSDKShareLinkContent Unable to share title and description when application is in live state iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have implemented FBSDKShareLinkContent to share contentURL, title, description and imageURL. I have implemented deep linking in the application which redirect it to apple store on selecting image from Facebook.

I have impmented following piece of code:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *shareContent = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
[shareContent setContentURL:url;
[shareContent setContentTitle:params.title];
[shareContent setContentDescription:description;
[shareContent setImageURL:imgURL;
```

It was working until my application redirect link wasn't in the live state. But now title and description is not visible when i post it to Facebook.

Comment: They recently documented a change for the Feed dialog, where it will not accept those additional parameters any more, if the target URL is a Facebook page, or points to an official app store – see the note here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#params / I would assume that they changed this internally so that it affects other ways of sharing as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered in the following link by the Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.6#params

It cleares that of your application is sharing itunes link of google play store link then the description added to the content of the sharing dialog will not be posted on the Facebook.